# Display new entry to all users with Socket.io, Express and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, handlebars.js

When a user adds an entry to the database, I am looking to reflect it on all open pages across users immediately. I am using Express, MongoDB and Handlebars with Socket.io. When User1 submits a new entry and it saves to MongoDB, User2 who is on the same page in a different browser, should instantly see the new entry on their page. I have tested the connection and am console logging when a new user is added. It is functioning for the singular client window, but is not broadcasting to all clients.

In server.js, I am saving the user:

```
// CREATE USER
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var randomNumbers = [];
  var min = Math.ceil(req.body.min);
  var max = Math.floor(req.body.max);

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.howMany; i++) {
      randomNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
    }
  };

  getRandomInt(min, max);

  // Create a new note and pass the req.body to the entry
  var newEntry = new Entry({
    name: req.body.name,
    min: req.body.min,
    max: req.body.max,
    howMany: req.body.howMany,
    numbers: randomNumbers
  });

  // And save the new note the db
  newEntry.save(function(error, data) {
    // Log any errors
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      // Or send the document to the browser
      res.send(data);
    }
  });    
});
```

and also receiving the socket.io connection

```
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
   });

   socket.on("newuser", function(data) {
    socket.emit("added", data);
   });
});
```

Making the AJAX call in /public/app.js and then emitting the data

```
    // When that's done
    .done(function(data) {  
      // Log the response
      console.log(data);
      socket.emit("newuser", data);
    });
});
```

The socket is initiated in my main.handlebars file and listens for added

```
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on("added", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

index.handlebars displays the page

```
  {{#each entries}}
  <div class="item">
        <span class="name"> {{this.name}} </span> <em> {{min}} : {{max}} </em>

        {{!--Maps over each number--}}
        <ul class="children">
          {{#each numbers}}
          <li> {{this}} </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>

       <div class="buttons">
        <button data-id={{this.id}} type="submit" class="delete button">REMOVE</button>
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button data-id={{this.id}} class="rename button">RENAME</button>

        <button data-id={{this.id}} class="updateNums button">MIN / MAX</button>
       </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
```

https://github.com/nathanchr/root-tree-app/tree/socket

Comment: You'll need to emit event and handle emit using socket.io to pass data between users and client. Look into socket.io documentation for more info.

Comment: Once I socket.emit, what is the function to actually push the DOM change?

Comment: You can refer to the docs for that. It's really simple. Also you will need to use sockets for inserting data instead of http call.

Comment: I've read the docs but don't see this specific case, any further clarity?

Answer (score 0):

The flow should go something like this:

1. Save entry in database
2. Emit a socket event from the server with the data the clients need
3. All clients should be listening for that event
4. On the event, use the data from the server to update the DOM

Handlebars (as far as I know) doesn't support data binding so you will need to update the DOM using JavaScript. Append the new entry to the list of existing entries. This will work great for live updates and whenever the user refreshes the page, they will just get a fully-hydrated template.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For step 3, would that just be a socket.on(event, function(newEntry) {...append newEntry to the DOM...} )

Comment: I tried adding socket.emit("new user added", function() {
        console.log("Success");
      }) to .done within my POST route but no success.